Organising data from a webpage, but when I type the print not all the data comes out
I was going to scrap some data from the webpage, but I cannot get what I want. So I checked if I can get the correct output at first stage.
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://kream.co.kr/products/36939'

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

print(soup)

Output shows tags only
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://kream.co.kr/products/36939'

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

product_info_div = soup.find('div', class_='product_info')

print(product_info_div)

Output is None
I would like to scrap the product number from
<div class="product_info" data-v-8b8c047e=""> MAW031L-00198-001 </div>

Why can't I scrape that number and how I should do it?

Is just me? product info for 605720VCPQ38803 does not exist on the link you provided.. seems that's related to https://kream.co.kr/products/47524

Sorry for the confusion, must be MAW031L-00198-001
I edited my question.

Something happens with that page that can't be parsed with Beautifulsoup, you can see the status of requests:
url = 'https://kream.co.kr/products/36939'
response = requests.get(url)
print(response.status_code)
print(response.text)

In this case, instead of Beautifulsoup, you can use Selenium:
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://kream.co.kr/products/36939")

for element in driver.find_elements("xpath", "//div[@class='product_info']"):
    print(element.text)

Use "find_element()" (specific match) or "find_elements()" (return a list of matches if there are multiple matches) to find the elements in the HTML and then, you can use ".text" to get the content of the specific tag.
You just need to adjust the "xpath" to your necessities. See the link for that.
